# Megilah Chumash Riddle

Tags: riddle, purim, names

Which four people’s names from the Chumash also come up as names in Megillas Esther?

Comment: The answers have five, so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yair is the easy one. (Mordechai's father in the Megillah, and [a son of Menashe in Parshas Pinchas](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/x/x0432.htm).)

Yehudah is the name of Yaakov's son in the Chumash, it appears in the Megillah as the name of the South Kingdom of Israel -- *with the exile that was taken with Yechanya, King of Judah*. I don't know if that counts.

Similarly, Kush is [a descendant of Noah in the Chumash](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/x/x0110.htm), and a place name in the Megillah, generally identified as Ethiopia. *Who reigned from* Hodu *[India?] to* Kush.

That leaves Tarshish, who is [one of Noah's great-grandchildren](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/x/x0110.htm) in the Chumash; a member of Achashveirosh's council of closest advisors in the Megillah (though he doesn't have a speaking role in this story); and for bonus credit, a place name elsewhere in Tanach (such as where Yonah is trying to flee on his ill-fated boat).

Answer (score 4):

Well being that it is Purim here are my answers.

בראשית: ד. יד.
הן גרשת אתי היום מעל פני האדמה ומפניך **אסתר** והייתי נע ונד בארץ והיה כל מצאי יהרגני

בראשית: ג. יא.
ויאמר מי הגיד לך כי עירם אתה **המן** העץ אשר צויתיך לבלתי אכל ממנו אכלת

אסתר: ט. יז.
ביום שלושה עשר לחדש אדר **ונוח** בארבעה עשר בו ועשה אתו יום משתה ושמחה

אסתר: א. ו.
**חור** כרפס ותכלת אחוז בחבלי בוץ וארגמן על גלילי כסף ועמודי שש מטות זהב וכסף על רצפת בהט ושש ודר וסחרת

> So we got Esther, Haman, Noach, and
>   Chur

However in all seriousness there is also Shimmee

שמות: ו. יז.
בני גרשון לבני **ו**שמעי**** למשפחתם

אסתר: ב. ה.
איש יהודי היה בשושן הבירה ושמו מרדכי בן יאיר בן **שמעי** בן קיש איש ימיני

Comment: But he asks for names of people in Chumash that appear as names in the Megillah.  So if it doesn't appear as a person's name in Chumash and also a name of some sort (person/place) in the Megillah, that wouldn't count.

Comment: Seth J - as noted in my answer it is answered in the Purim spirit